# Connected roads QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I have a map with a set of roads obtained from Open Street Maps which I have filtered.  It leaves some portions of roads not connected to to the main network of roads, which can cause problems when using some tools like Shortest Path.

My question is if there is a way to separate a set of roads into networks that are interconnected and know how many separated networks are in a map. For example if there are roads that connect points A, B, C, and D in any way, but none of these point are connected to E and F, but E and F are connected, then there are two separate road networks, one that includes A,B,C and D, and one network with E and F.

EDIT: Found a plugin called Disconnected Islands that was able to separate the different disconnected networks in a graph.

Comment: This might help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/how-to-find-disconnected-islands-in-a-road-network-layer-using-qgis