# Identify discrete groups of connected lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 with extensions including Network Analyst.

I have a set of lines (geodatabase feature class), some of which join and some do not. I would like to give each discrete group of connected lines a unique ID to allow statistics on number of lines in the group, total length, etc. Are there any existing tools that will help me do this?

I have a manual workflow using repeated Select By Location that can achieve this but it is time consuming. I could try to script/ModelBuilder the task, but suspect (due to inexperience) this will take me longer than the manual workflow. I have built a Network Dataset based on the lines but am not sure if that helps.

Any suggestions? ArcGIS Pro 3.0 is potentially available if there is a solution that only exists there.

[image: sample of line dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time after posting my question I found this previous one:
[Unsplit/Dissolve multiple touching lines in Stream Network using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132723/unsplit-dissolve-multiple-touching-lines-in-stream-network-using-arcgis-desktop)

That question has an accepted solution that does not involve scripting (based on buffering) and other solutions that use Python. The buffer-based solution works for me although takes a very long time to run; I have not tried the scripts.

Answer (score 3):

[Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) your lines with the unsplit lines parameter.  Then use a [spatial join tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) to populate the original lines with the OIDs of the joined features.  Any lines that share nodes in the original data will then share a dissolved OID from the joined data and any single line features will have a unique OID from the joined data.

This will work if and only if the groups actually share nodes.  You can use [topology tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/topology-in-arcgis.htm) to edit your line work after you identify areas where lines do not share nodes base on your user-defined tolerances.

There is also [this tool](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Attribute-adjacent-geometries-with-increasing-count-values) which might help you get started coding a tool if you are interested in creating a recursive selection tool.

Comment: I believe Unsplit only works where just 2 lines share an endpoint, and here there are many points where several lines meet.

Even on groups which happen to have 2 lines I am not seeing an unsplit result, though. Endpoints should be coincident since the lines were generated from a process involving Add XY Coordinates and then XY To Line. So I need to look into that further.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative coding approach is to use the python module [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) and pull out the *connected components*.

```py
import networkx as nx

# Simple shapefile, no MZ values
fc = r"c:\scratch\test2.shp"

#  Reads and returns a directed graph
dG = nx.read_shp(fc,True) 

# Convert to an undirected graph
uG = dG.to_undirected()

# Report number of components
x = nx.number_connected_components(uG)
print("Number of sub-components = " + str(x))

# Get components, this is a list of set objects which contain 
# tuples of XY coordinates of the nodes in the component
connected_components = list(nx.connected_components(uG))
```

Its then up to you to match the nodes to their edges and pass through to the shapefile a simple count, that being the component number in the list `connected_components`. An example of this is shown in the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/finding-disconnected-islands-in-road-network-layer-using-qgis/184535#184535) within a QGIS environment, but note the comments later about precision issues. I'm unsure if this is relevant to ArcGIS Pro as it is using a newer version of networkx (2.7.1).

If you are not comfortable with coding in python then I suspect @GBG approach is best and easier to understand.

Comment: I might come back to this but it is a bit beyond my own capabilities at the moment. Thanks!